# Unable to restart nginx

Tags: server, nginx

I need to restart the process. What do I do when I keep seeing these messages? Do you need more commands?

```sh
$ nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()

$ service nginx start
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

$ systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-05-29 13:28:29 KST; 26s ago
  Process: 24508 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 31955 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 31952 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 13077 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 29 13:28:27 ip-172-26-12-170 nginx[31955]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 29 13:28:27 ip-172-26-12-170 nginx[31955]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 29 13:28:28 ip-172-26-12-170 nginx[31955]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 29 13:28:28 ip-172-26-12-170 nginx[31955]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 29 13:28:29 ip-172-26-12-170 nginx[31955]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
May 29 13:28:29 ip-172-26-12-170 nginx[31955]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
May 29 13:28:29 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 29 13:28:29 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
May 29 13:28:29 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 29 13:28:29 ip-172-26-12-170 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 0):

A application is currently listening on the on port `80`. Most likely it is a other instance of `nginx`.

#### Find application that is listening on the socket

With the [netstat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/netstat.8.html) command you can find the application which is currently listening on the socket. Also use [grep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/grep.1.html) to filter the output of `netstat`.

```
$ netstat -lpn | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      780/nginx: master p 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      780/nginx: master p
```

The last entry of the list `780/nginx` tells you the `PID` of the process currently listening on the port `80`.

#### Find and kill the application

With [ps](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ps.1.html) you can see the process structure of the process using the socket:

```
$ ps f -g780
   PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
   780 ?        Ss     0:00 nginx: master process nginx
   781 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
   782 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
   783 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
   784 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
   785 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
   786 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
   787 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
   788 ?        S      0:00  \_ nginx: worker process
```

With the [kill](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/kill.1.html) command you can now terminate the process which uses the socket:

```
$ kill 780
```

If that does not terminate the process with `-9`:

```
$ kill -9 780
```

Then try to restart your `nginx` service.

Comment: If that other process (nginx, pid 780 in this case) is controlled by `systemd` (which isn't unlikely for Ubuntu), then this won't help because systemd will just restart it. But the basic idea is correct: find and stop the other process that ist listening on port 80. Or reconfigure them to use different ports.

Comment: Of course I tried to kill the process. The first time I kill `nginx: master`, I get `nginx: worker`. I also killed it. I also tried restarting the service.

Comment: And the kill did not work?

Answer (score 0):

In the future, here's something that might come in useful. You can check the syntax of Nginx's configuration files by running:

nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

The error output will give you a hint at what the problem is as well as the line number.

or:

debug with command:

$ service nginx configtest

Which outputs something like:

Testing nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "stub_status" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nginx_status:11
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: Yes, but in this particular case nginx cannot start (despite a correct config file) because the port 80 is already occupied by another process.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I came to know something new.